# Grouping array for every four in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this : 
`<?php array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);` 
How to group that array into another array for every 4 numbers like :

```
<?php 
arr(1) = 1,2,3,4;<br>
arr(2) = 5,6,7,8;<br>
arr(3) = 9,10,11;<br> 
?>
```

in PHP.